# How do I use the .Include method to get multiple related properties (of different types) from database?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ssms

I want to get information from a Table called 'Appointments' in my database and also get all the 'Treatments' and 'Users' that each appointment is related to.
I tried using `.Include` from `System.Data.Entity` but could only make it bring a single related property where as I need both of them.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
        public override List<Appointment> GetAll()
        {
            using (DB = new DBModel())
            { return DB.Appointments.Include(a => a.Treatments).ToList(); }
        }
```

Is there a way I can use include to bring more then 1 related property?
and if not how can I bring more then 1 related property then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to chain the includes just like this

```
 return DB.Appointments
   .Include(a => a.Treatments)
   .Include(a => a.Users)
   .ToList();
```